# How to logout user in specific time

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple application with login in webforms and i need to automatic logout user in specific time, due updates
e.g in 13:30 i need to logout user from website a redirect to login page.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: did you have tried to recycle application pool periodically?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you use IIS as a Webserver. The easiest way to take your App offline is to put a app_offline.htm in the web root folder. IIS will redirects all request to this file.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2012/02/03/easiest-way-to-take-your-web-site-offline-iis-6-0-or-iis-7-5-with-net-4-0/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, when a user interacts you can check the time and if the time has passed your due time, then flush his session details.
Because if a user has logged in, and he is not interacting with the website for few hours, you can not log out by going into his browser.

You can also store login time stamp into a database and you can compare it with current time when the user interacts the website next.